# Is there a plugin for pyramid to display documentation?

Tags: python, pyramid, documentation-generation

Is there a plug-in for pyramid that automatically display a documentation from a pdf file or a tex file? what's the regular way something like the documentation in pyramid is written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know Pyramid is just using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and then this is integrated into [Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) via Github.

Comment: Not a problem, if this answer solved your question could you please mark it as such? Then it won't show up for other users looking for unanswered questions.